# How to structure java.io.File code to support JUnit testing?

Tags: java, javafx, junit

I'm trying to set up some initial tests for a JavaFX application, but specifically, I want to try and test the TreeView component, and I'm wondering how best to isolate access to the file system so that it can be tested (without having a dependency on my own file system). This is the project that I'm trying to test: https://github.com/mfearby/magnificat (it's a very basic thing at the moment and all it does is show a TabPane with some TreeViews pointing to the file system).

When you change the selected tab, it writes to an INI file so that when the app loads, it can restore those tabs. So I'd like to be able to test that this works, but it would depend on my own file system structure. The only testing I've ever done is with RedGate SQL Test, so I've never tested a GUI app, so please forgive the newbie question.

Should I somehow alter my FileTreeItem class which uses java.io.File.listFiles() so that it uses a virtual file system when testing (perhaps with Jimfs)? If I do this, how do I modify my class so that it uses Jimfs when testing but java.io.File when not in testing? Should I set a global variable (eek!) and act accordingly within my FileTreeItem class? That sounds awful but I'm scratching my head just wondering how best to test file system access without creating an absolute abomination.

Is it right to even modify the application code in such a way to accommodate a testing tool (apart from good coding practises in general) or should it be up to the test framework to do all the fakery to get the app to function in a testable way?

Any advice or pointers to "the right way" to do this would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend switching to nio and use `Path`s. That way you can use an in-memory file system like JimFS for testing (https://github.com/google/jimfs)

Comment: So if I use java.nio instead of java.io, then I should be able to get my JUnit tests to use Jimfs to "fake" a file system without my calls to java.nio methods being aware of it? That sounds ideal.

Comment: I have now refactored my project to use Paths and I can switch between the default file system and Jimfs and it all just works nicely. I haven't written any tests yet but I can certainly switch easily between the two file systems, so that's a good start. Thanks again, Neil.

Comment: Sorry Marc, just saw this now. Yes, one of the major goals of NIO was to abstract and allow strange file systems that are transparent to the application.

Comment: No worries. Now that I've sorted that problem, I've uncovered another (nothing to dwell on here, though). I have to decide how best to decouple my objects so that I can test them independently. Strategy or Observer Pattern. Dependency Injection and/or use an Event Bus. Decisions, decisions :-)

Comment: Design is my favorite part of programming, should be fun :P

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself what it is you're unit testing.

Are you actually unit testing the writing to file? Why? You shouldn't test the JVM, but trust that it has already been tested.

So if not that, then what are you testing?

The file format? I.e. what you write get be read and understood? That part can be unit tested by using [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) and [`ByteArrayInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) instead, so refactor the code so you can test the writing/reading logic using byte streams when unit testing, but file streams when running code.

Comment: I recently refactored my Settings.java file so that I could use methods that returned or received Strings instead of just reading and writing the INI file directly, in anticipation of being able to use them in a test. I want to test that I'm saving the currently selected tab to an INI file (or string) and load them again from the INI file (or string) when I start the app, so I'm not trying to test the JVM.